# iptables accept only three-way handshake

Tags: iptables, tcp

With iptables I want to accept three-way handshake of a TCP connection and then drop the connection. Is it possible, if so how?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) - search for --tcp-flags

You should accepts packets with SYN, SYN+ACK and ACK flags set, and drop everything else.

Comment: This won't work since on a "running" tcp-connection many packets contain ACKs. Even on long downloads this is set even it's not necessary. Have just been testing this.

Comment: yes, 'ACK' but not 'SYN' AND 'ACK'. Step two of handshake (syn/ack) has both flags set to 1, not just ACK.

Comment: That's not, what you said. :-p
You say: "SYN, SYN+ACK and ACK" - that last ACK is "just ACK" - isnt it? (AND: The third packet of the handshake is "just a normal" packet containing just an ACK)

Comment: damn not enough coffee i guess.. let me rethink...

Comment: Ok another idea, after the rules above, you can limit the number of packets ( -m connbytes, --connbytes (number) and --connbytes-mode packets ) to allow only three packets (both directions).... or you could just limit packets to 3 with tcp :) (not sure if it works though, 1 in two out or vice-versa)

Comment: What about simply using the conntracking? -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j DROP?