# iptables rule to allow only incoming TCP-handshake

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, tcp

I need some [`iptables`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) rule to allow only **incoming TCP-handshake**. So I need to allow flags `SYN` and `ACK`. But I can't figure out what should be in `???` position in my rule?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK ??? -j ACCEPT
```

It should be `SYN` or `ACK` or what else. Alas [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=iptables+-A+INPUT+-p+tcp+--tcp-flags+SYN%2CRST%2CACK%2CFIN+SYN+-j+ACCEPT) can't explain this position in rule..

There is nothing [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/406671/iptables-accept-only-three-way-handshake) that answers my question - no rule examples and explanations. Also nothing about incoming handshake, and even nothing about `--tcp-flags` by the specified link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iptables accept only three-way handshake](https://serverfault.com/questions/406671/iptables-accept-only-three-way-handshake)

Comment: explainshell.com shows you (?), but the explanation reads: _The first argument mask is the flags which we should
       examine, written as a comma-separated list, and the second argument comp is a comma-separated list
       of flags which must be set.  Flags are: SYN ACK FIN RST URG PSH ALL NONE.  Hence the command
        iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST SYN
       will only match packets with the SYN flag set, and the ACK, FIN and RST flags unset._ Which is the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want allow only incoming TCP handshake and deny outgoing connections, you don't need a lot of rules with tcp flags checking. Several rules with state checking are enough:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -I OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
```

But aside the question itself, this request seems like strange. Maybe this is the XY problem. Please describe your original issue.